# Contourplot for big equations

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

1/sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + 1 - sqrt(2) sqrt(x^2 + y^2) (x/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + y/sqrt(x^2 + y^2))) - 1/sqrt(x^2 + y^2 + 1 - sqrt(2) sqrt(x^2 + y^2) (x/sqrt(x^2 + y^2) + y/sqrt(x^2 - y^2)))

trying to do a contour plot of an equation like this but can't get wolfram alpha or mathematica to accept it. It is plotting nothing. When I do it on wolfram alpha computation time exceeded.

Do I need to simplify this expression?

Comment: Please post the WL/Mathematica code you tried.

Comment: This `ContourPlot[1/Sqrt[x^2+y^2+1-Sqrt[2]Sqrt[x^2+y^2](x/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]+y/Sqrt[x^2+y^2])]-1/Sqrt[x^2+y^2+1-Sqrt[2]Sqrt[x^2+y^2](x/Sqrt[x^2+y^2]+y/Sqrt[x^2-y^2])],{x,-1,1},{y,-1,1}]` works for me in both Mathematica and WolframAlpha BUT that is 176 characters on that line and there seems to be a line length limit in WolframAlpha